# Laravel - "WhereHas" query: different for each user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Sorry, this is a bit complicated to explain, but basically: The thread table has many messages. A thread has these columns:

```
id, deleted_at_sender, deleted_at_receiver_ sender_id, receiver_id
```

The messages table has these columns

```
thread_id, user_id, body
```

With my query, I am trying to get the threads which have not been deleted by the user who the thread was sent to. For instance, if `user1` sends a message to `user2`, `user2` can delete it and he should not be able to see it, while `user1` should still be able to see it.

I have got that query set up already and it works flawlessly (kind of)

```
$messages = Message::select('*', \DB::raw('max(created_at) as created_at'))
        ->where($get_user_id, uid())
        ->groupBy('thread_id')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->whereHas('thread', function ($q) {
            $q->whereNull('deleted_at_receiver');
        })
        ->paginate(10);
```

Where is the problem you may ask? It's this line: `$q->whereNull('deleted_at_receiver');`. You see, depending on if the current logged in user is the receiver or sender of the mail, I cannot really fill that in. For now, I have sort of hardcoded the `deleted_at_receiver` column at this line.

I need to somehow figure out a way to  determine if the thread was created by the current logged in user and change `$q->whereNull('deleted_at_receiver');` depending on if the user is the sender or receiver.

Any help is highly appreciated. I have spent over 2 days trying to figure this out with no luck. Please help guys.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the rest of the query, sounds like you could solve that using slightly more advanced where queries. Something like this, perhaps, although I'm not 100 % sure this is what you're after.

```
->whereHas('thread', function ($q) use ($user_id) {
    $q->where(function ($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->whereNull('deleted_at_receiver')
            ->where('receiver_id', $user_id);
    })-orWhere(function ($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->whereNull('deleted_at_sender')
            ->where('sender_id', $user_id);
    });
})
```

Perhaps you'll need to use `whereNested()` for the or clause. But I'm afraid I'm unable to check if it works or comment further at the moment. Hopefully it'll at least get you going in the right direction. :)